# ImageField: save filename only

Tags: django, django-models

I have model with `ImageFile` field:

```
def upload_course_cover(object, filename):
    return '/media/courses/%s_%s' % (Course.objects.aggregate(Max('id'))['id__max'] + 1, filename)

class Course(models.Model):
    # ...
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_course_cover,  blank=True)
```

When the image is saved, into `cover` field will be writen full image path `/media/courses/id_filename.ext`, but I want store only image name `id_filename.ext`.
How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change what it stores in the database - unless you create your own custom field; or use a `CharField`.

If you just want to display the filename:

```
import os
c = Course.objects.get(pk=1)
fname = os.path.basename(c.cover.name)

# if cover's name is /hello/foo/bar.html
# fname will be bar.html
```

However, since you have image field - you can get lots of benefits out of it, for example - to get the URL to display the image in an `img` tag:

`<img src="{{ c.cover.url }}"
         alt="cover image for {{ c.name }}"
    />`

You can also get some other benefits, for example:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    # ....
    cover_height = models.IntegerField()
    cover_width = models.IntegerField()

    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_course_cover,
                              height_field=cover_height,
                              width_field=cover_width,
                              # your other options...
                              )
```

Now you can do:

`<img src="{{ c.cover.url }}" height="{{ c.cover_height }}" width="{{ c.cover_width }}">`

Comment: But if i rename or change folder, where I store covers, I will need correct all pathes to images in DB. This is not good, I think. Or not?

Comment: You should always make sure your URLs are still valid even if you change the physical paths on the server. The phyiscal location of the file can be moved around, but you should not change the URL.

To change the path on the server, simply change the MEDIA_ROOT directory.

Comment: I wanted to use basename of file in FileField and DateTimeField then build upload_to path via DateTimeField. But it's impossible because Django file storage class has inflexible architecture - it uses bare string name to store / read related file instead of model instance. So I have to use duplicate CharField for basename, that's really sad.

Answer (score 0):

"When the image is saved, into cover field will be writen full image path /media/courses/id_filename.ext"

To be precise, this is not true. Only the relative path from your MEDIA_ROOT is saved in the database. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

(ImageField has the same properties as FileField)

To save only the filenames, you could

1. Add a new CharField to store the names
2. Use os.split() to get just the filename when called